# How to iterate over all n-tuples in n lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list made up of n sublists of varying size i.e.
`lists = [[] for _ in range(n)]` and these sublists have been filled by user input.
How do I iterate over all possible n-tuples of the sublists?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please post your code, input files and desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested for loops:

```
for ntuple in list_of_tuples:
    for item in ntuple:
        take_action(item)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
result = [take_action(item) for item in ntuple for ntuple in list_of_tuples]
```